# Access attributes of objects by string

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to access object attributes by a variable.
I have a bunch of strings, like "location", "rotation", "hide_render" that point to attributes of objects and would like to access their values.

```
#this works, not what I look for:
print(bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location)

#I'm looking for something equivalent to this:
myAttribute = 'location'
print(bpy.data.objects['Cube'][myAttribute])

#I know this workaround exists, but it's not exactly elegant,
#because i would have to implement every attribute like this:
if myAttribute == 'location':
    print(bpy.data.objects['Cube'].location)
```

Comment: `getattr(ob, "location")`. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: @scurest 's solution is likely the most appropriate way but there have been occasions when alternatives are needed as such I'll add `eval("ob." + my_attribute)` assuming `ob` was defined as your object.

Comment: Thanks you both, getattr works perfectly in that situation, [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) would require `ob` to be in the local scope, but I'll keep it in mind

Comment: + it's really not safe to use `eval` on user input strings. It can execute malicious code easily. Try with attribute's name `name, quit()` and see what happens